# AngularJS smart-table global config implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, global, smart-table

table. For displaying buttons I am using this part of code,with a template

```
 <ul class="pagination">
     <li><div class="pageNumberClass" st-pagination="" st-template="/AppScripts/vendor/template/pagination.custom.html" st-items-by-page="itemsPerPage" colspan="4"></div></li>
 </ul>
```

This link for template st-tamplate="/App...." is repeating on all pages. How can I make global configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it at application level

```
  angular.module('myModule', []).
    config(function(stConfig) {
      stConfig.pagination.template = 'my-custom-pagination-tmpl.html';
    });
```